# hover submenu won't work in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, submenu

I'm totally new to css, but I ventured to create a website using a wordpress theme. The theme is supposed to be IE compatible but my hover submenus aren't clickable when in IE7,8 or 9.
That said, I've created style-IE*.css files and pointed to them. I've increased the index #. But it's still not working.
Here is the site: [www.mariasherranz.com](http://www.mariasherranz.com)

and here is the menu script (canned from the theme, with some color and font changes):

```
.navigation {
text-transform: uppercase;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
display: none;
}

.navigation ul.menu li a {
    font: 26px 'Marvel', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.navigation ul.menu li ul {
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

    .navigation ul.menu li ul li {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
        float: left;
    }

        .navigation ul.menu li ul li a {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background:none;
        }

            .navigation ul.menu li ul li a:hover {
                color: #000000;
                background:#FFFFFF;
            }

        .navigation ul.menu li ul li ul {
            margin: 36px 0px 0px 0px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 20;
            display: none;
        }

            .navigation ul.menu li ul li ul li {
                margin: 0px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                float: right;
            }

                .navigation ul.menu li ul li ul li a {
                    margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
                }

                .navigation ul.menu li ul li ul li ul {
                    display: none !important;
                }
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get to that!

Answer (score 0):

My website does something very very similar with IE.  It's a vertical sub-menu instead of a horizontal, but when in IE if you hover over the top menu, the sub-menu appears, but you have to move the mouse at lightning speed to highlight a link or the menu disappears.  One thing you should look strongly at (I looked at your site) is this:

padding-left in your .css files for (.navigation ul.menu li a  )

Worth noting, it appears to me that your theme also has a style-IE9.css file, which probably overrides some of the style.css attributes.

When I worked with the Dev Tools on IE9 (first time ever) I could see that the issue partially resolved when I changed the padding-left to 0px in the IE9.css file under (.navigation ul.menu li a).  A say partially, because the sub-menu titles for About ( Bio and Resume) were "squished" really close to the top menu.